# Prevent Android keyboard from reverting back to alphabetic mode

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an App which requires the input of a sequence of space-separated hex digit groups (much like a product key) into an EditText, such as `AB34 67EF ...`

The problem is that every time a numeric digit is entered followed by space, the Android keyboard automatically switches back to alphabetic mode, which is both confusing and highly annoying to the user.

For example, when typing the two groups above, the keyboard will remain in numerics mode when '3' is pressed, but then switches to letters mode when the space key is hit after '4' - meaning the user then has to manually switch back to numerics before entering '6'.

The EditText control (below) has textNoSuggestions flag set for the input type, but no matter what inputType and what keyboard settings I change, I cannot get the keyboard to stay in numerics mode following a space.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Is there any way to force the keyboard to stay in the current mode after a space character is entered or, alternatively, a way to programatically switch the keyboard mode?

Comment: how does the user enter a space ? On my SG3, the native keyboard has no space in number mode.  I put `android:inputType="number"`

One solution I see is to have 4 edit text and switching focus from one to the other, doing so the user just fill his code and they are nicely separated. More a trick than a real solution, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The app is actually running on a tablet, so the spacebar always shows. But even on my Nexus 4, there is still a small spacebar in number & symbol modes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm finding the same problem in a Nexus 5 phone.

Comment: @AlejandroMezcua Not really. I ended up using a TextWatcher to monitor the input and auto-insert spaces appropriately. But if the user still chooses to press space while in numerics mode, the keyboard reverts to alphabetic.

Comment: @adelphus OK, my problem is that I am inserting the spaces (or other separators) automatically so if the user switches to numeric input, after I put a separator the keyboard decides that it has to switch to QUERTY back. But it does not happen in every phone. The Nexus 5 and an HTC One Mini change automatically, but a Galaxy S4 does not. I haven't been able to figure out how to detect that keyboard state nor how to keep it in a given state.

Comment: @AlejandroMezcua yes, I had that too. In my case it was because I was using setText() to update the control from within the TextWatcher.afterTextChanged() callback. To fix it, I converted the code to only use replace() on the afterTextChanged() Editable parameter. Basically, not using setText() anywhere appeared to stop the keyboard from automatically reverting. I also looked into setting the keyboard state, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi @AlejandroMezcua, I have same issue. I also using TextWatcher and after that Edittext has same situation like you. so now, how you can solve it. Thank u

Answer (score 3):

I needed the same. The inputType `textVisiblePassword` did the trick for me.
Reference: [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```